# Changing Label From Another Form

Tags: c#

I've already searched other questions for this answer (and that is how I got as far as I did) and everything seems to be working except the end result. I am getting no errors but I am not getting the desired input and cannot figure out why.

I have two forms, Form1 and login. On Form1 I have a label called "label2" that is going to display text entered from a textbox on login upon button press. Here is the code I have so far:

Form1 Code:

```
    public void SetTextForLabel(string myText)
    {
        this.label2.Text = myText;
    }
```

login Code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.userName = textBox1.Text;
        Form1.password = textBox2.Text;

        Form1 frm = new Form1();
        frm.SetTextForLabel(textBox1.Text);

        this.Close();
    }
```

The program works. I click login on form1, it opens up the login form. I enter my username and password and it passes the input to my form1 variables. Since label2 on form1 is not public, I made a public method to use on my login form that will change my label2.Text, but it doesn't and I'm not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're instantiating a new copy of form1 why?

Comment: winforms or webforms?

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your description, I believe Form1 opens Login form, and on login form there is `button1` that is probably your login button.

If this is all correct then I think you have your logic wrong.

your button on Form1 that opens login form should do the following

```
using(Login loginForm = new Login())
{
     if(DialogResult.OK == loginForm.ShowDialog())
     {
         SetTextForLabel(loginForm.TextAccessorProperty);
     }
     else
     {
          MessageBox.Show("Invalid login");
     }
}
```

then login forms button one should just do,

```
//Login logic
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
// (no need for form.close())
```

Answer (score 0):

This creates a new instance of `Form1` but it's not shown, and I suspect this is not the reference you need.

```
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    frm.SetTextForLabel(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me, Just write one more line to show form1.

i.e.

```
frm.Show();
```

I think it will work. :)

Comment: This works but I never closed Form1 to begin with. So when I use frm.Show() it brings up a new Form1 with the updated input (and now my code works) but I have two Form1s open now.

Comment: ok, so you mean to say at the same time both the forms are open and you are clicking on one form, which should change the label text on another. Please let me know my understanding with respect to your problem, is it correct??

Comment: If both the forms should be open at the same time and you need the label text to be updated when clicked on another form. Just create the form1 object outside the button click event and it should be static and then try to use. It is working fine for me. Let me know if you still face issue. :)

Comment: This works, but when I set the method SetTextForLabel as static, the code "this.label2.Text = myText;" no longer works.

Comment: Dont set that method static. Just set the form intance to static. Thats it. It is working fine for me.